# Android Toolbar return button didn't work after adding productFlavors

Tags: android, toolbar, android-productflavors

Before adding `productFlavors` in `build.gradle(Module:app)`, the return button in `Toolbar` works.
But once I added `productFlavors` into `build.gradle(Module:app)` for `Build >> Generate Signed APK...`, the return button become invalid.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.comp548.note">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NoteEditActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(Module:app) after adding `productFlavors`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comp548.note"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.comp548.note.free"
            versionName "1.0-free"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId "com.comp548.note.paid"
            versionName "1.0-paid"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

toolbar.xml in `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_note_edit.xml in `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.comp548.note.NoteEditActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/note_edit_toolbar" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_margin"
        android:name="com.comp548.note.NoteEditFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fNoteEdit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_note_edit"
        android:layout_below="@id/note_edit_toolbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.comp548.note;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.note_list_toolbar);
        // Set the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteEditActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_exit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

NoteEditActivity.java:

```
package com.comp548.note;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class NoteEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_edit);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.note_edit_toolbar);
        // Set the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Enable return button
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        NoteEntity noteEntity = (NoteEntity) intent.getSerializableExtra("noteEntity");
        // Set values for Views in NoteEditFragment
        if (noteEntity != null) {
            NoteEditFragment noteEditFragment = (NoteEditFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fNoteEdit);
            noteEditFragment.setValues(noteEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

App screenshots:
[image]

After remove the `productFlavors` from `build.gradle(Module:app)` the return button works again.

Why the return button on `Toolbar` didn't work after adding `productFlavors`.

How to fix it if I still want to add `productFlavors`?

Comment: post your `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: I added `MainActivity.java` which contains `onOptionsItemSelected()`. The `onOptionsItemSelected()` only handles `exit` function currently. Also three screenshots were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay in your `NoteEditActivity` add the callback method `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and do the following:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It should fix your issue, allowing the toolbar back button to execute the action of the back button. Hope this helps.

Comment: @J.W well please mark it as the solution so that the question reflects so. I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** You put different applicationId for each flavor.
In manifest you set metadata for parent activity, but during building flavor all packages are automatically moved to package *com.comp548.note.free* or *com.comp548.note.paid*. Your metadata points to com.comp548.note.MainActivity though your actual activity is located under com.comp548.note.paid|free.MainActivity.

**Solutions:**

1. Create separate manifests for each flavor with metadata points to correct packages.
2. Handle it at runtime like **KudzieChase** described.

Comment: thank you, the solution 2 worked. But I am not quite understand the solution 1 ? Do you have an example link that I can study?

Comment: @J.W Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets

Comment: Thanks. It would take me some time to digest these contents :)